# How old was Big Joe when he became a level 5 killjoy?

Tags: killjoys

Big Joe is supposedly the youngest Killjoy to reach level 5, and the oldest to keep it.

Dutch is the only Killjoy to join at level five. Surely she must have joined at an early age.

How old was Big Joe?

Answer (score 1):

Dutch was tutored by Khlyne since she was 8, which was 20 years from the shows present day (for 6 of which Dutch had run from Khlyne). If she joined the RAC when she left Khlyne's tutelage she'd have been 22.

For the fact about Big Joe to be true,  he had to reach level 5 killjoy before that age,  and been a lower level before then. Other than that we don't know.